# Undefined is not an object (evaluating container.setState)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native and I got the issue while running my application the code is as follows:

```
  var container;
   function onPress(){
   container.setstate({
     info:"bye"
   })
 } 
class Demo extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state={
  info:"hI"  
   }
 } 
 componentDidMount(){
 container=this;     
   }
 }
```

I want to set the state of a variable outside of my class but I am getting the error.

Comment: What is `container`? The code you have given doesn't have container defined anywhere.

Comment: container is an global variable sorry i forgot to mention

Comment: You mean a component? You don't set states on variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved it:

Outside React.createClass.

```
  socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    console.log('connect');
  });


  function initStream() {
    getLocalStream(true, function(stream) {
      localStream = stream;
      container.setState({ selfViewSrc: stream.toURL() });
      container.setState({ status: 'ready', info: 'Please enter or create room ID' });
    });
  }
```

Inside React.createClass.

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    container = this;
    initStream();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing "counter" as param to "componentDidMount", that is causing an error. Any way you should use callbacks from some component to setState in it.

Comment: Sorry container is an global variable

Answer (score 0):

To set the state from a parent component in react you can do this:

```
class Demo extends Component{
     someOtherFunction = () => {
         this.props.updateMyState({info: bye});
     }
 }

 class Container extends Component{
     updateMyState = (newState) => {
         this.setState({myStateHere: newState});
     }
     render() {
         <Demo updateMyState={this.updateMyState}/>
     }
 }
```